# Laravel how to make package RouteServiceProvider compatible with 5.2 and 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

The signature for RouteServiceProvider->boot() method changed from

```
public function boot(Router $router)
{
    parent::boot($router);
}
```

to

```
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
}
```

I need to update a package that was implemented for 5.2 to be compatible with both 5.2 and 5.3. How would I go about doing this? I've never worked with packages before.

If I remove the argument I get the next error in 5.2:

> Declaration of PackageNS\RouteServiceProvider::boot() should be compatible with Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::boot(Illuminate\Routing\Router $router)

And if I keep it, it returns similar error in 5.3:

> Declaration of PackageNS\RouteServiceProvider::boot(Illuminate\Routing\Router $router) should be compatible with Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::boot()

Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

This is the contents of my service provider:

```
use Illuminate\Routing\Router;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

Class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    protected $namespace = 'ProviderNS\Controllers';

    public function boot(Router $router)
    {
        parent::boot($router);
    }

    /**
     * Define the routes for the application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Routing\Router  $router
     * @return void
     */
    public function map(Router $router)
    {
        $router->group(['namespace' => $this->namespace], function($router)
        {
            require __DIR__.'/../Config/routes.php';
        });
    }


}
```

Comment: My advise: don't extend a core Laravel service provider in a package that might get used in different Laravel versions.

Comment: Can you show the contents of your `Service provider` as there might be a way to abstract it to work.

Comment: Of course. It's in the edit.